# Why is process killed with free memory in other zones?

Tags: kernel, out-of-memory

I've read in my syslogs that the Out of Memory Killer is terminating processes when the "Normal" memory zone is underneath the minimum limit, but I still have tons of free memory in the "HighMem" zone. I'm confused as to why that is happening and if there's anything I can do to stop it. I had assumed that if there was no free memory in one zone, the kernel would hand out memory from a different zone unless the process required memory from a specific zone, but in this example the application causing the OOM is python and I couldn't thinkof a reason why that would need memory in the Normal zone specifically.

Here's a typical example that showed up recently:

```
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: python invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x2084d0, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: python cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: CPU: 0 PID: 593 Comm: python Tainted: G           O 3.14.24-wt-ldr-TC #4
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: Hardware name: Eurotech, Inc. Catalyst TC/Catalyst TC, BIOS 04.08.05.01 02/03/2017
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: 00000000 00000000 f336fd7c c171e79e f4f03580 f336fdd8 c171b7a0 c1908d18
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: f4f03954 002084d0 00000000 00000000 f336fdb8 c1106774 00000000 00000000
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: f336fdb4 002084d0 00000000 f336fdd8 c13ac8d2 c1109634 f336fde8 f4f042e0
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: Call Trace:
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [<c171e79e>] dump_stack+0x4b/0x75
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [<c171b7a0>] dump_header.isra.9+0x77/0x1ee
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [<c1106774>] ? shrink_slab+0xb4/0xf0
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [<c13ac8d2>] ? ___ratelimit+0x82/0x100
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [<c1109634>] ? do_try_to_free_pages+0x404/0x420
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [<c10f9fac>] oom_kill_process+0x1dc/0x360
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [<c10486d6>] ? has_ns_capability_noaudit+0x36/0x50
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [<c1048704>] ? has_capability_noaudit+0x14/0x20
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [<c10f9c87>] ? oom_badness+0xa7/0x100
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [<c10f9d29>] ? oom_scan_process_thread+0x49/0xc0
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [<c10fa4d4>] out_of_memory+0x1f4/0x2d0
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [<c10fe557>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x937/0x950
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [<c10fe58d>] __get_free_pages+0x1d/0x30
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [<c103b3be>] pgd_alloc+0x1e/0x130
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [<c103dfc0>] mm_init+0xc0/0xf0
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [<c103e256>] mm_alloc+0x56/0xa0
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [<c1143ddf>] do_execve+0x19f/0x5a0
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [<c1144389>] SyS_execve+0x29/0x40
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [<c172a6be>] sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x12
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: Mem-Info:
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: DMA per-cpu:
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: CPU    1: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: Normal per-cpu:
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 179
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 130
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: HighMem per-cpu:
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   6
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  51
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: active_anon:3208 inactive_anon:67 isolated_anon:0
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: active_file:1330 inactive_file:3589 isolated_file:0
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: unevictable:0 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: free:290674 slab_reclaimable:1335 slab_unreclaimable:3757
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: mapped:1448 shmem:251 pagetables:105 bounce:0
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: free_cma:0
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: DMA free:3388kB min:64kB low:80kB high:96kB active_anon:80kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15992kB managed:15916kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:36kB slab_unreclaimable:128kB kernel_stack:16kB pagetables:4kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 839 1996 1996
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: Normal free:3556kB min:3672kB low:4588kB high:5508kB active_anon:3820kB inactive_anon:56kB active_file:168kB inactive_file:284kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:892920kB managed:860136kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:72kB slab_reclaimable:5304kB slab_unreclaimable:14900kB kernel_stack:744kB pagetables:204kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:749 all_unreclaimable? yes
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 9257 9257
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: HighMem free:1155752kB min:512kB low:1776kB high:3040kB active_anon:8932kB inactive_anon:212kB active_file:5152kB inactive_file:14072kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:1184968kB managed:1184968kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:5792kB shmem:932kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:212kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: DMA: 21*4kB (UE) 15*8kB (UEM) 9*16kB (UM) 9*32kB (UM) 5*64kB (UMR) 3*128kB (MR) 2*256kB (ER) 1*512kB (R) 1*1024kB (R) 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 3388kB
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: Normal: 333*4kB (UEM) 269*8kB (M) 0*16kB 1*32kB (R) 1*64kB (R) 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 3580kB
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: HighMem: 1085*4kB (UM) 1427*8kB (UM) 1298*16kB (UM) 1116*32kB (UM) 933*64kB (UM) 723*128kB (UM) 506*256kB (UM) 280*512kB (UM) 103*1024kB (UM) 28*2048kB (UM) 121*4096kB (MR) = 1155820kB
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: 5177 total pagecache pages
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: 0 pages in swap cache
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: Free swap  = 0kB
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: Total swap = 0kB
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: 523470 pages RAM
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: 296242 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: 0 pages reserved
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes swapents oom_score_adj name
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [  301]     0   301      807      232       3        0             0 upstart-udev-br
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [  303]     0   303      768      256       3        0         -1000 udevd
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [  372]     0   372      741      157       2        0         -1000 udevd
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [  373]     0   373      741      152       2        0         -1000 udevd
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [  795]     0   795     1172      202       3        0             0 vsftpd
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [  849]     0   849      674      176       3        0             0 rpcbind
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [  910]     0   910      711       66       2        0             0 upstart-socket-
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [ 1004]     0  1004     1670      398       3        0         -1000 sshd
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [ 1010]     0  1010      727       52       3        0             0 rpc.idmapd
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [ 1016]   102  1016      814      181       2        0             0 dbus-daemon
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [ 1058]   101  1058     8070      659       8        0             0 rsyslogd
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [ 1081]   107  1081      739      240       3        0             0 rpc.statd
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [ 1125]     0  1125     1038      151       4        0             0 getty
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [ 1132]     0  1132     1038      154       4        0             0 getty
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [ 1145]     0  1145     1038      152       4        0             0 getty
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [ 1146]     0  1146     1038      150       4        0             0 getty
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [ 1151]     0  1151     1038      150       4        0             0 getty
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [ 1160]     0  1160      640      151       2        0             0 xinetd
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [ 1166]     0  1166      545      102       3        0             0 acpid
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [ 1167]     0  1167      654      174       3        0             0 cron
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [ 1168]     0  1168      617       69       3        0             0 atd
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [ 1179]     0  1179      900      134       3        0             0 irqbalance
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [ 1189]   103  1189     6116      669       7        0             0 whoopsie
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [ 1235]     0  1235      843      176       3        0             0 rpc.mountd
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [ 1386]     0  1386     4937     1061       6        0             0 python
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [ 1387]     0  1387      535       79       3        0             0 watchdog
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [ 1395]     0  1395      600      139       3        0             0 getty
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [ 1396]     0  1396     1038      151       4        0             0 getty
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [  592]     0   592      823      262       3        0             0 ldrc_script.s
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [  593]     0   593     4680      710       5        0             0 python
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: [  594]     0   594      653       59       3        0             0 cron
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 1386 (python) score 2 or sacrifice child
Feb  2 04:10:01 ldr kernel: Killed process 593 (python) total-vm:18720kB, anon-rss:2184kB, file-rss:656kB
```

I'm assuming that the oom-killer was triggered because the "Normal" zone had dropped below the min of 3672kB as shown on this line:

```
Normal free:3556kB min:3672kB low:4588kB high:5508kB active_anon:3820kB inactive_anon:56kB active_file:168kB inactive_file:284kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:892920kB managed:860136kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:72kB slab_reclaimable:5304kB slab_unreclaimable:14900kB kernel_stack:744kB pagetables:204kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:749 all_unreclaimable? yes
```

But the "HighMem" zone has plenty of space left:

```
HighMem free:1155752kB min:512kB low:1776kB high:3040kB active_anon:8932kB inactive_anon:212kB active_file:5152kB inactive_file:14072kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:1184968kB managed:1184968kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:5792kB shmem:932kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:212kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
```

So why would the kernel keep handing out memory in Normal to the point where it sinks under the min value and then have to start killing processes, when it could instead have used some of the free space in HighMem? The kernel version is 3.14.